# Firebase set() callback is not firing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var data = {name:"test", age:20};
var ref = new Firebase('http://test.firebaseio.com');
ref.set(data, function(error){
 // Callback comes here
 if(error){
    console.log(error);
 }
 else{
    console.log("Data successfully");
  }

});
```

But the callback is not firing at all but it is inserting in the database

Comment: When I copy/paste your code into a JavaScript console of Chrome, it prints `Data successfully`. So it is likely something specific to your system/how you execute the code. Can you set up a jsfiddle or similar system that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Thank you Frank, I'm just a dunmb ass, I omitted the an "r" in the error and got it well on Stackoverflow... Thank you man for your support. It is now fixed.

Comment: Typos happen to everyone adediran. Thanks for confirming what the problem was!